# Notation question related to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Someone asked me a question today about the dimensionality of:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})=\{ a+b \cdot \sqrt{3} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\} $$

I am thinking that they are interpreting it as a vector space when they ask a question about dimensionality. Seeing it has two parameters and we could interpret $a$ and $b \cdot \sqrt{3}$ as two independent vectors (not multiples of each other by irrationality of $\sqrt{3} $ argument).

I would say the answer is $2$.

Am I correct in thinking this, is it me or is this weird notation, has anybody seen this before? Here is the guy's textbook:
[image]

I ask this because I found the question interesting, but the most confusing thing one can do is using weird notation and not explaining what you mean.

Comment: This is standard notation for a [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension).  And, you are correct:  as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ has dimension $2$.  Indeed a basis is $1, \sqrt 3$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into is :D

Comment: But they should write "Let $Q$ be **the** set of rational numbers", or better "the field of rational numbers", rather than "**a** set".

Comment: Presumably "is a vector space over" is cut off in the picture.

Comment: Thanks for helping out guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a $\Bbb Q$-vector space, ${\Bbb Q}(\sqrt 3) = \{a+b\sqrt 3\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Q}\}$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Q}^2$ with the assignment $$a+b\sqrt 3\mapsto{a\choose b},$$
since addition in both spaces are componentwise, in particular,
$$(a+b\sqrt 3) + (c+d\sqrt 3) = (a+c) + (b+d)\sqrt 3.$$

Comment: Yes, I also considered this argument, thanks for making it explicit and showing there exists a bijective structure-preserving map, hence these structures are isomorphic and must have the same amount of basis vectors.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely true that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, with standard basis $\{1, \sqrt3\}$. It is even very common to think about it like that. In fact, given a field extension $F$ over a field $E$, the dimension of $F$ as a vector space over $E$ is a very importand invariant, called the *degree* of the extension.

Comment: Very fascinating, I'm taking a course on abstract algebra next block - very much thrilled. So far I've only seen groups and simple applications of finite fields and quotient rings - but we'll delve into this later. Thanks, Arthur.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the text is missing from the picture; I'm assuming that's the part o the text that clarifies what they mean : in particular one can see in the picture "$\mathbb{Q}$ with dimension" and so I think the rest of the text says something like "blabla is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with dimension ". So I don't understand what clarification you need. Let me adress your points about the answer though.

First of all, the textbook is very imprecise when it says "let $\mathbb{Q}$ be a set of rational numbers". In my answer I'll be assuming they meant "*the* set of rational numbers".

Then, your intuition is correct that there are two parameters, and so the dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ "should be $2$".

But the notion of dimension is a precise one and so you have to go beyond the intuition and actually prove your answer. The point you were trying to make when you said "we could interpret $a$ and $b\sqrt{3}$ as two independent vectors" can be made precise by stating that $\{1,\sqrt{3} \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

The proof is easy : it is a generating family, by definition; and it is linearly independent because $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational (you should check the details if this isn't clear).

Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ has a basis with $2$ elements, so it is of dimension $2$.

Comment: Suppose they are not linearly independent.  We get that there exists some nontrivial combination 
$$1 \cdot x + \sqrt{3} y =0 \implies -x = \sqrt{3}y \implies -x \cdot y^{-1} = \sqrt{3}$$
But this is impossible because $-x$ and $y^{-1}$ are both rational, and $\sqrt{3}$ is not, we reach a contradiction. We conclude that the only linear combination that leads to the zero vector is the trivial combination, hence these two vectors are linearly independent.