# Notation issue with 'Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.'

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation

> Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I haven't seen this notation $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ before. Can someone clarify what it means?

Comment: what do you man by "vector" field ? Do you mean field ?

Comment: $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{2} : a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$

Comment: Vector space. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Its vector space dimension is $2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047495/notation-question-related-to-mathbbq-sqrt3?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is the smallest field which contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$

The axioms of fields dictate

$\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\{{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}}\}$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Omnomnomnom's comment, $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ denotes the set of values $p(\sqrt{2})$ can take for $p$ a $1$-variable polynomial function whose coefficients are in $\Bbb Q$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is a root of $x^2-2$, this is equivalent to writing $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]=\Bbb Q+\sqrt{2}\Bbb Q$. You can probably spot a basis of this $2$-dimensional vector space now. Similarly, $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is of dimension $3$.